# MySql trying to improve query performance but got error on a column

Tags: mysql

This is really 2 questions in one but I'll try to make it as much to the point as possible.

I showed my initial query to a friend that told me the performance could be improved further with a sub select (**using MySql Here**).

Unfortunately I could not get his query to work since I had a `Error Code: 1054
Unknown column 'e.id' in 'where clause'`

His query below: would appreciate if someone tells me why it cannot recognise `e.id`.

```
SELECT e.id AS event_id, er.name AS event_name, er.revision AS revision, er.start_date AS event_dates
 FROM `events` AS e
 INNER JOIN 
 (
    SELECT event_id, revision, start_date 
    FROM event_revisions
    WHERE YEAR(start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
    AND revision = (
       SELECT MAX(er_tmp.revision) 
       FROM event_revisions AS er_tmp
       WHERE er_tmp.approved = 1
       AND e.id = er_tmp.event_id
    )
 ) AS er ON (e.id = er.event_id)
 INNER JOIN member_events AS me ON (me.event_id = e.id)
 WHERE 
  e.enabled = 1 AND 
  e.deleted = 0
 GROUP BY event_id
 ORDER BY event_dates
```

This is my original query:

```
SELECT e.id AS event_id, er.name AS event_name, er.revision AS revision, er.start_date AS event_dates
FROM `events` AS e
INNER JOIN event_revisions AS er ON (e.id = er.event_id)
INNER JOIN member_events AS me ON (me.event_id = e.id)
WHERE 
    e.enabled = 1 AND 
    e.deleted = 0 AND 
    er.revision = (
        SELECT MAX(er_tmp.revision) 
        FROM event_revisions AS er_tmp
        WHERE er_tmp.approved = 1
        AND  e.id = er_tmp.event_id
    )
    AND YEAR(er.start_date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
GROUP BY event_id
ORDER BY event_dates
```

The second question is: why would his query be faster than mine?

Any input it is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try using backticks (`) for column & table names. Also it is not recognized because "e.id" is in another query (it is in the sub-query)

Comment: hmm, so I can retrieve the event_id from the other query? like `event_revisions.event_id = er_tmp.event_id`

Comment: I don't think you can. The deepest subquery is executed first, in order to build a temporary table from which data can be extracted by parent queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AD 1. Because sub select:

```
 SELECT MAX(er_tmp.revision) 
    FROM event_revisions AS er_tmp
    WHERE er_tmp.approved = 1
    AND  e.id = er_tmp.event_id
```

is "called" for each row in Your's query.

(AD 2) and as @Dor told You, You are using alaias from sub query

Comment: Thats right, got it to work now :D performance was way slower than mine though, mine: Execution Time : 0.002 sec, his: Execution Time : 1.058 sec any ideas why such a big differnece?